# jquery .each() doesn`t work with my div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are some divs in my html and this js code in another file. Can`t find the problem why it doesn't work.

```
$(".inputDiv").each(function () {
    $(this).focus(function () {
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "2px solid dodgerblue");  
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).css("border-bottom", "2px solid gray");
    });
});
```

Other scripts from this file works fine.
My piece of html

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/login}">
        <div class="inputDiv">
            <div>
                <span>login</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="inputLogin dataField" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="inputDiv">
            <div>
                <span>password</span>
            </div>
            <input type="password"  class="inputPass dataField" name="password" >
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Увійти" id="buttonEnter" disabled="false">
    </form>
```

I want to change div border-bottom when clicking on it and also change it back when clicking other zone.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I think you should use `hover` instead of `focus` on div elements. WIth css this should be easy.

Comment: @AndreNuechter css doesn`t applies when i click on div

Comment: There are no click handlers in the function you have shown...

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()`. All the event binding methods automatically apply to all selected elements.

Comment: Are you adding the input elements dynamically? Is the jQuery code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute to `inputDiv` element like (just click inside the div to set focus):

```js
$(".inputDiv").focus(function() {
    $(this).css("border-bottom", "2px solid dodgerblue");
    $(this).css("outline", "none");
}).blur(function() {
    $(this).css("border-bottom", "2px solid gray");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputDiv" tabindex="0">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```